# Github fork immediate dependency

Tags: github

What is the best practice to fork a repo and immediately reference it as a dependency in a project?

Found a library on Github to use on a project. The library has a minor bug that needs to be addressed before it can be used on my project. Plan to fork the library, address the bug, and create a pull request. It may take a week for the pull request to be merged in (it may never be accepted). Is it poor practice to reference the forked repository as a dependency?

I don't plan to delete the forked repository even after pull request is merged. If request is merged in a timely manner before the project is completed, the dependency will be updated to reference the original library. If it isn't merged before the project is done, future developers can see it is a forked repository and follow the pull request history.